# How to deal with lazy load elements on cypress?

Tags: cypress, browser-automation

How to deal with lazy load?

Most of my test are failing it is because i can't target properly using the `scrollIntoView` and `scrollTo` the elements and it doesn't load the element. It is necessary to use a plugin called cypress-recurse? or can i do it on vanilla cypress? even if i this:

```
it('Visit the website', () => {
    cy.scrollTo('bottom')
    cy.wait(5000)
});
```

still it doesn't load the middle part of the page. Most of the elements are images are failing

Answer (score 2):

The scroll commands can be a bit finnicky. I would suggest force the lazy load on each element from top to bottom, like

```js
cy.get('lazy-element').each($el => {
  cy.wrap($el).scrollIntoView()
})
```

Other than that, I recall seeing a way to force eager loading via webpack but it depends on your app.